# simplexmlelement object doesn't list all children

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have this xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
    <item>
      <!-- Basic Product Information -->
      <g:id><![CDATA[FSK10]]></g:id>
      <title><![CDATA[title]]></title>
      <description><![CDATA[desc]]></description>
      <g:product_type><![CDATA[Default Category]]></g:product_type>
      <g:product_type><![CDATA[Default Category > Cat1]]></g:product_type>
      <g:product_type><![CDATA[Default Category > Cat1 > Cat2]]></g:product_type>
      <link><![CDATA[https://www.link.com]]></link>
      <g:image_link><![CDATA[https://www.link.com/media/image.jpg]]></g:image_link>
      <g:condition><![CDATA[new]]></g:condition>
      <g:availability><![CDATA[in stock]]></g:availability>
      <g:quantita><![CDATA[9]]></g:quantita>
      <g:price><![CDATA[68.50EUR]]></g:price>
      <g:brand><![CDATA[FISKARS]]></g:brand>
      <g:ean><![CDATA[6411501967701]]></g:ean>
      <g:mpn><![CDATA[FSK10]]></g:mpn>
      <g:identifier_exists><![CDATA[TRUE]]></g:identifier_exists>
      <g:shipping_weight><![CDATA[1.70kg]]></g:shipping_weight>
    </item>
 </rss>
```

When I call `SimplexmlElement` in php it doesn't list all the children, it is missing the tags with the namespace `g:` :

```
  $xml = simplexml_load_string( $data ); 
  $attributes = $item->children();  //get the rss
  echo htmlentities( $xml->asXML() ) . '<br />';
  foreach ( $attributes as $attr ) {
    echo "$attr<br />";
  }
```

How to list all the tags?

Comment: `foreach ( $rss->children('g', true) as $item ) {` Read about namespace in xml

Comment: Ok it works they are children of rss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @splash58 comment: you can use `children` command with namespace as argument (and setting true to prefix).

Code:

```
$attributes = $item->children('g', true);
foreach($attributes as $atrr) {
    echo "$attr<br />";
}
```

Full documentation can be found [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php)